# Angular change variable on component load

Tags: angular

I have this ruote configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'score', component: ScoreComponent }
];
```

when the component score is loaded I want to change the value of a variable in parent component.

The variable **title** is located in parent component template:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-menu [variablesForMenu]='variablesForMenu'></app-menu>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">            
            <h1>
                {{title}}
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I do?

I would like to use EventEmitter but I do not know how

Comment: you can use this code to detect  when the component loaded. <router-outlet
  (activate)='onActivate($event)'> this event fired when thecomponent loaded. And you can get the title via service beetwen parent component and score component.

Comment: I added three ways to do it where one of them is event emitter.

Comment: How can i use the third way? I do not have child component on template, it is loaded dinamically by router

Comment: If you're not importing child's component in parent's view, then event emitter isn't the right solution. I thought that by 'parent' you mean inserting one component into another. Well, if those component aren't related you need to use BehaviorSubject.

Comment: I tried the first solution, it works! thanks

Comment: The code in child.component.ts should be: `ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.em.next(true);}`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways to do it:

1. Use BehaviorSubject, subscribe to it in parent and call `next` in child on init.

SomeService.service.ts

```
em: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Parent.component.ts

```
variableToChange: any;
sub: Subscription;

constructor(someService: SomeService){}

ngOnInit() {
  sub.add(this.someService.em.subscribe(value => this.variableToChange = whatever));
}
```

Child.component.ts

```
constructor(someService: SomeService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.em.next(true);
}
```

---

2. Pass variable from parent to child as input, then in child on init change that variable.

Parent.component.ts

```
variableToChange: any;
```

Parent.component.html

```
<child [variable]="variableToChange"></child>
```

Child.component.ts

```
@Input() variable: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.variable = 'whatever';
}
```

---

3. Use EventEmitter

Child.component.ts

```
@Output() em: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
  this.em.emit('something');
}
```

Parent.component.html

```
 <child (em)="setVariable($event)"></child>
```

Parent.component.ts

```
 variableToChange: any;

 setVariable(event) {
  this.variable = event; // event is emitted value
 }
```